# I gave items to a Charity Shop to sell, and signed up for Gift Aid on the donated items when sold. Should I put this on my Self-Assessment?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, charity, self-assessment

I gave items to a Charity Shop to sell, and signed up for [Gift Aid on the donated items when sold](https://www.bhf.org.uk/how-you-can-help/donate/gift-aid). This increases the profit to the charity, who send me an annual letter informing me how much Gift Aid was claimed. Should I put this on my Self-Assessment? Does it decrease my taxable income?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you fill in a Self Assessment Tax Return then yes you should include that amount in the "one-off donations" total.

It will effectively decrease your taxable income if you are a higher rate tax payer, there are some worked examples on [this page](https://www.gov.uk/donating-to-charity/gift-aid):

> Example
> You donate £100 to charity - they claim Gift Aid to make your donation £125. You pay 40% tax so you can personally claim back £25.00 (£125 x 20%).

The way that this "claim back" is done is by adjusting the personal allowance to have the effect of making you pay £25 less tax.

Comment: Note that your example **only** applies if you pay higher rate tax.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, that's why I literally said " if you are a higher rate tax payer".... :)